# Merging two text files into new one (back and forth every new line) using C in Linux using system-calls

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

So the assignment is merging two text files in Linux using system calls:

- 1.txt:

> Hello,
>
> my class!

- 2.txt:

> Today is
>
> a very nice
>
> day

- NEW.txt:

> Today is
>
> Hello,
>
> a very nice
>
> my class!
>
> day

Problem is I get (sorry for putting this as code sample):

```
Hello,
+Today is
my class!


a very nice

day
```

The + sign keeps changing between ("#", "(", "0", "_", ..) with each execution..

Why do I have extra new lines and this thing with the *?
Thank you in advance.

My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
int p1,p2,pNEW;
char Buff1[1], Buff2[1];
p1=open(argv[1],O_RDONLY);
p2=open(argv[2],O_RDONLY);
pNEW=open(argv[3],O_WRONLY|O_CREAT,0644);

while(read(p1,&Buff1,1)>0 || read(p2,&Buff2,1)>0)
{
    do{
        write(pNEW,&Buff1,1);
        if((Buff1[0]=='\n'))
            break;
    }while(read(p1,&Buff1,1)>0);

    do{
        write(pNEW,&Buff2,1);
        if((Buff2[0]=='\n'))
            break;
    }while(read(p2,&Buff2,1)>0);
}

close(p1);
close(p2);
close(pNEW);
}
```

Comment: `while(read(p1,&Buff1,1)>0 || read(p2,&Buff2,1)>0)`?  Among other things, you need to think about what your code will do if your files are different sizes.

Comment: The `||` operator can "short circuit", so both `read()`s may not happen.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp There's no "can" about it - it *will* in this case, reading all data from `p1` before ever getting to `p2`.

Comment: Hint: you should write a function that reads one line from a file. This boils essentially down to implementing the [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) function. Once you have written this function the rest is easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to retain if you have read all your file or not, because the read in the first while will ... read, and that's not what you want.

Code edited after comment :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

bool WriteLineFromFile(int dst, int src, bool *srcTerminated)
{
    int     lastChar    = EOF;
    char    currentChar;
    ssize_t nbCharRead;
    ssize_t nbCharWrite;

    do {
        if ((nbCharRead = read(src, &currentChar, 1)) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s : read(src, &buf, 1) : src=%d, errno='%s'.\n", __func__, src, strerror(errno));
            return (false);
        }
        // End of file
        if (nbCharRead == 0) {
            (*srcTerminated) = true;
            // Adding '\n' if necessary
            if (lastChar != '\n' && lastChar != EOF) {
                currentChar = '\n';
                while ((nbCharWrite = write(dst, &currentChar, 1)) != 1) {
                    if (nbCharWrite < 0) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "%s :  write(dst, &buf, 1) : dst=%d, errno='%s'.\n", __func__, dst, strerror(errno));
                        return (false);
                    }
                    sleep(1);
                }
            }
            return (true);
        }
        // Writing a char into the dst file
        while ((nbCharWrite = write(dst, &currentChar, 1)) != 1) {
            if (nbCharWrite < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s :  write(dst, &buf, 1) : dst=%d, errno='%s'.\n", __func__, dst, strerror(errno));
                return (false);
            }
            sleep(1);
        }
        lastChar = currentChar;
    } while (currentChar != '\n');

    return (true);
}

bool FileMerging(char *inputPathFile1, char *inputPathFile2, char *outputPathFile)
{
    int  inputFile1      = -1;
    bool file1Terminated = false;
    int  inputFile2      = -1;
    bool file2Terminated = false;
    int  outputFile      = -1;
    bool returnFunction  = false;

    // Openning all the file descriptor
    if ((inputFile1 = open(inputPathFile1, O_RDONLY)) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s : open(inputPathFile1, O_RDONLY) : inputPathFile1='%s', errno='%s'.\n", __func__, inputPathFile1, strerror(errno));
        goto END_FUNCTION;
    }
    if ((inputFile2 = open(inputPathFile2, O_RDONLY)) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s : open(inputPathFile2, O_RDONLY) : inputPathFile2='%s', errno='%s'.\n", __func__, inputPathFile2, strerror(errno));
        goto END_FUNCTION;
    }
    if ((outputFile = open(outputPathFile, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644)) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s : open(outputPathFile, O_RDONLY) : outputPathFile='%s', errno='%s'.\n", __func__, outputPathFile, strerror(errno));
        goto END_FUNCTION;
    }

    // Alternativly print a line from inputFile1 and inputFile2 to outputFile
    do {
        if (!file1Terminated) {
            if (!WriteLineFromFile(outputFile, inputFile1, &file1Terminated)) {
                goto END_FUNCTION;
            }
        }
        if (!file2Terminated) {
            if (!WriteLineFromFile(outputFile, inputFile2, &file2Terminated)) {
                goto END_FUNCTION;
            }
        }
    } while (!file1Terminated || !file2Terminated);


    returnFunction = true;
    /* GOTO */END_FUNCTION:
    if (inputFile1 != -1) {
        close(inputFile1);
    }
    if (inputFile2 != -1) {
        close(inputFile2);
    }
    if (outputFile != -1) {
        close(outputFile);
    }
    return (returnFunction);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 4) {
        fprintf(stderr, "This program wait 3 arguments on the command-line : inputFilePath1 inputPathFile2 outputPathFile.\n");
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (!FileMerging(argv[1], argv[2], argv[3])) {
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile.  It is missing `#include <unistd.h>`  for the `read()` function.

Comment: Never access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the command line parameter was actually entered by the user

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: when calling C library functions, like `open()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror()`  with your error message.  `perror()` will output your text message AND the text message indicating the error to `stderr`.

Comment: this is the syntax for `read()`  'ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);`.  In C, an array name degrades to the address of the first byte of the array.  so this kind of statement: `read(p1,&Buff1,1)>0`  should be: `read( p1, Buff1, 1 ) > 0`.   Notice no `&` (address of) operator for `Buff1` because that name degrades to the address of `Buff1`.   Similar considerations exist for the other calls to `read()` and calls to `write()`

Comment: Note: there is no guarantee that the last line of a text file ends with a '\n' so should keep track of 'if already printed some text and the returned value from `read()` is 0' as a second reason to break out of a do...while() loop

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) insert a reasonable space: inside parens, inside brackets, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators.  2) follow the axiom:  *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: Wow wow wow wow !!
Okay Okay. I have just taked the code given in the question and modify the "read/write" algorithm. I will edit it to give a more clean code. But my indentation is based on tabulation, and my IDE display 2 space per tabulation. Because I prefer 2 space over 4 space.

Comment: code edited, but now that I reread your comment, it seem you misplaced them : Most of it are for Julian Broud that for me.